# How to calculate vertex normals for imported models?

Tags: c++, 3d, shader

I am using Assimp to import 3d model data, however the normals provided with the mesh don't look as they would in any other 3D-application. while i am not aware whether other 3d applications compute normals or just import it from the file, i can't figure out that if the problem is with the way that i render or with the normlas.

Regardless of whether other apps use normals provided with the mesh or compute them, I have to implement a ComputeNormal method.

As far as i can tell, my rendering pipeline is good because before when i was using hard-coded vertex data to render a cube, i was working perfectly.

```
CMesh ModelLoader::processMesh(aiMesh * mesh, const aiScene * scene)
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<short> indices;
    for (UINT i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        Vertex vertex;
        vertex.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
        vertex.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
        vertex.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
        if (mesh->mNormals)
        {
            vertex.NormalX = mesh->mNormals->x;
            vertex.NormalY = mesh->mNormals->y;
            vertex.NormalZ = mesh->mNormals->z;
        }
        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];

        for (UINT j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
    }

    CMesh ret = CMesh(vertices, indices);
    return ret;
}
```

Though normals are loaded correctly, but the model doesn't look like what it should or would in any other 3D application.

Comment: What does "the model doesn't look like it should" even mean. Calculating the "correct normals" is flat-out impossible in the general case, because there are no "correct" normals - these are direct properties of the 3D model which ultimately need to be specified by the 3D artist, and are not implied by the geometric shape of the model. Doing the latter is only a heuristic, and it tends to break at the most interesting parts of the model, usually.

Comment: How to calculate surface normals for a 3d mesh, that's what i meant in short.There are many articles online that explain it theoretically, but my implementation doesn't seem to work

Comment: Where is your implementation? The code you posted just copies the normals if they're present but does not calculate any.

Comment: Nx = (p2 - p1)y * (p3 - p1)z - (p2 - p1)z * (p3 - p1)y

Ny = (p2 - p1)z * (p3 - p1)x - (p2 - p1)x * (p3 - p1)z

Nz = (p2 - p1)x * (p3 - p1)y - (p2 - p1)y * (p3 - p1)x

This is basically what i implemented